# Profile fails to get created for a New Registered User in Django

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm working on a new Django project to get students registered and to get a profile created for each student after the registration. I get an error when the user register.

***ERRO***

> **ValueError at /students/register/**
>
> **Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.**

Below are my code snippets:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='students/profile_pics')
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='biography')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, *kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

**views.py**

```
def register_student(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('student_course_list')
    else:
        form = StudentRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'students/student/registration.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class StudentRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(help_text='Enter a valid email address')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import register_student

urlpatterns = [
    ###
    path('register/', register_student,
         name='student_registration'),
]
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class StudentsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'students'

    def ready(self):
        import students.signals
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ###
    'students.apps.StudentsConfig',
 
]
```

I've tried everything but nothing is working. At the admin side the users get registered but no profile is created for them.

**I am awaiting your noble responses and better solutions**
Thank you.

Comment: may be you need to remove second signal, you try to make an update without values

Comment: Alright I'll check on that

Comment: I have removed the second signal but I still get the same error: Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.

Answer (score 1):

**Second signal is not required.** It gives error because the below signal is updating the object in the database which is not created yet.

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: I'll take a look at that fix

Comment: I get the same error. Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.